# Visual inheritance in WinForms across 3 Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

Is it possible to enable visual inheritance across 3 forms?

In the application I see the inheritance but in the designer I only see the inheritance from the first level, but not from the second level.

My first level looks like this: 3 Buttons on a Panel
[image]

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form {
    public BaseForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private DBConnection _dbCon = null;

    protected DBConnection DbCon {
        get {
            if (_dbCon == null) {
                _dbCon = DBConnection.Instance(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlEdiops"].ConnectionString);
            }
            return _dbCon;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    }

    #region Button Events

    #region Button Save
    protected void SetBtnSaveEnabled(bool enabled) {
        btn_Save.Enabled = enabled;
    }

    protected virtual void OnBtnSaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    }
    #endregion Button Save

    #region Button Add
    protected void SetBtnAddEnabled(bool enabled) {
        btn_Add.Enabled = enabled;
    }

    protected virtual void OnBtnAddClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    }
    #endregion Button Add

    #region Button Delete
    protected void SetBtnDeleteEnabled(bool enabled) {
        btn_Delete.Enabled = enabled;
    }

    protected virtual void OnBtnDeleteClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    }
    #endregion Button Delete

    #endregion Button Events
}
```

My second level Looks like this: The Buttons form level one and a new panel with labels and textboxes.

[image]

```
public partial class BaseMessageForm : BaseForm {

    public BaseMessageForm() : base() { }
    public BaseMessageForm(int previousRecordID) : base() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And know my third level: Here are the Buttons from level  one but not the textboxes from level two.
[image]

```
public partial class VororderForm : Partnerverbindungen.Forms.BaseMessageForm {
    public VororderForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Does anyone knows why this happens?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of inheritance I would go for shared components. You make a panel with three buttons, and then use that panel (with code) in three forms (or in as many as you like).

Comment: This is a way, but i wanted to learn something about visual inheritance.

Comment: `public VororderForm(() : base() {}` -- Close that File and all the others in that chain of inheritance, clean / rebuild the Solution, try to open the derived-derived Form. You should get a Designer issue. Remove `: base()`, close everything again, rebuild the Project, reopen

Comment: Your answer didn't work in my case. No Issue.

Comment: Are you telling me? If *something* didn't work, then you didn't follow the procedure. The `: base()` thing added to the derived / derived `VororderForm` class is not important, it's just meant to generate an issue, so you have to deal with it, but you can do without. What matters is that you close all the Forms in the chain and rebuild the Solution / Project (you may different Projects). The open up the different classes in the chain and see the result

Comment: In the `BaseMessageForm` class, move back the `InitializeComponent` method to the default constructor and call `: this()` instead of `: base()` in the parameterized constructor.

Comment: @Jimi I did your steps but they're not the Problem.

Comment: I found the issue by my self. In the Default Constructur from BaseMessageForm I forgot the InitializeComponent-Methode. 
@dr.null That was my Mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue by my own. It's the same thing what @dr.null answered. Thanks for your help everybody.